# PHPExcel two separate chart in one sheet?

Tags: charts, phpexcel

I used the bellow code to generate chart using PHPExcel. But now i cant draw two chart that each of them should use from separate data source in one sheet, so any change or suggestion is welcome.

```
    $workbook->getProperties()
            ->setCreator("TRAINING")
            ->setLastModifiedBy("TRAINING")
            ->setTitle("TRAINING")
            ->setSubject("TRAINING")
            ->setDescription("TRAINING")
            ->setKeywords("TRAINING Document")
            ->setCategory("TRAINING Document");
            $rotation = "";
    // Define variables for chart settings 
    $startRow_num = '3'; 
    $totalWhiteRows = 2; 
    $category_start = $startRow_num+1;
    // get the total number of rows that data source is write in plus one white row for A1 
    $total_rows = count($course_rep)+$totalWhiteRows;
    $start_ofChart = $total_rows+1;    
    for($sh = 0; $sh <= 1; $sh++)
    {

        //$sheet = $sheet.''.$sh;              
        //$excel->setActiveSheetIndex(3);

        if($sh == 0)
        {   
            $sheet = $workbook->createSheet($sh);
            $sheet = $workbook->setActiveSheetIndex($sh);
            $workbook->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('worksheet1');
            $sheet_name = $sheet->getTitle();
        }
        elseif($sh == 1)
        {   //$sheet = $workbook->createSheet($sh);
            $sheet = $workbook->setActiveSheetIndex($sh);
            $workbook->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('worksheet2');
            $sheet_name = $sheet->getTitle();
        }
        //echo "<pre/>"; print_r($sheet_name); exit;
        $workbook->getActiveSheet()->getTabColor()->setRGB('CC000#'); 
        $styleHeadings = array(
                                'borders' => array(
                                    'allborders' => array(
                                        'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
                                            'color' => array('argb' => '#DBDBB7'),
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                'font' => array(
                                    'bold' => true,
                                    'size' => 20 
                                    ),
                                'fill' => array(
                                    'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_GRADIENT_LINEAR,
                                    'startcolor' => array(
                                        'argb' => 'E9E9E9',
                                    ),
                                    'endcolor' => array(
                                        'argb' => 'E9E9E9',
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'alignment' => array(
                                'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER
                                ),   
                    );
        if($this->mng_auth->get_language()=='en')
        {
            $sheet->setRightToLeft(false); 
        }
        else
        {  
            $sheet->setRightToLeft(true); 
        }
        $sheet->getStyle('G1:O2')->applyFromArray($styleHeadings);
        if($sh == 0)
        {
            $sheet->setCellValue('G1','ÑÇæÑ æÑÓ åÇ Èå ÇÓÇÓ ÑÊÈå ÔÇÑÏ');
        }
        else
        {
            $sheet->setCellValue('G1','ÑÇæÑ æÑÓ åÇ Èå ÇÓÇÓ ãÍá æÙíÝå ÔÇÑÏ');
        }
        $sheet->getStyle('G1:O2')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
        //$sheet->setCellValue('H11','ãÌãæÚ ÔÇÑÏÇä'); 
        $sheet->mergeCellsByColumnAndRow(6,1,14,2);
        if($sh == 0)
        {
            $sheet->fromArray(  
               $course_rep,
               NULL,
               'A'.$startRow_num 
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $sheet->fromArray(  
               $course_jobLocBasedrep,
               NULL,
               'A'.$startRow_num  
            );

        }
        $sheet->fromArray(  
               $chart_total_stdOfCourse,
               NULL,
               'Q'.$startRow_num  
            );
        $labels = array(
          new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', $sheet_name.'!$B$'.$startRow_num, null, 1),
          new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', $sheet_name.'!$C$'.$startRow_num, null, 1), 
          new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', $sheet_name.'!$D$'.$startRow_num, null, 1), 
          new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', $sheet_name.'!$E$'.$startRow_num, null, 1), 
        );

        // find the end row number of data source because we write from A2 so A3 is the start of main data 

        $categories = array(
          new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', $sheet_name.'!$A$'.$category_start.':$A$'.$total_rows, null, 4),   
        );
        $values = array(
          new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', $sheet_name.'!$B$'.$category_start.':$B$'.$total_rows, null, 4),
          new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', $sheet_name.'!$C$'.$category_start.':$C$'.$total_rows, null, 4),  
          new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', $sheet_name.'!$D$'.$category_start.':$D$'.$total_rows, null, 4),  
          new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', $sheet_name.'!$E$'.$category_start.':$E$'.$total_rows, null, 4),  
        );     
        $series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
          PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART_3D,     // plotType
          PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STACKED,  // plotGrouping
          array(0,1,2,3),                                     // plotOrder
          $labels,                                        // plotLabel
          $categories,                                    // plotCategory
          $values                                         // plotValues
        );  

        $series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);

        // Total student chart 
        $total_labels = array(
          new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', $sheet_name.'!$Q$'.$startRow_num, null, 1),
          new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', $sheet_name.'!$R$'.$startRow_num, null, 1), 
        );

        // find the end row number of data source because we write from A2 so A3 is the start of main data 

        $total_categories = array(
          new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', $sheet_name.'!$Q$'.$category_start.':$Q$'.$total_rows, null, 4),   
        );
        $total_values = array(
          new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', $sheet_name.'!$R$'.$category_start.':$R$'.$total_rows, null, 4),  
        );     
        $total_series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
          PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART_3D,     // plotType
          PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STACKED,  // plotGrouping
          array(0,1),                                     // plotOrder
          $total_labels,                                        // plotLabel
          $total_categories,                                    // plotCategory
          $total_values                                         // plotValues
        );  

        $total_series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);
        $layout1 = new PHPExcel_Chart_Layout();    // Create object of chart layout to set data label 
        $layout1->setShowVal(TRUE);                   
        $layout1->setManual3dAlign(true);
        $layout1->setXRotation(20);
        $layout1->setYRotation(20);
        $layout1->setPerspective(15);                                              
        $layout1->setRightAngleAxes(TRUE);                                              
        //$layout1->setShowPercent(TRUE);
        //$layout1->setShowCatName(TRUE);
        //$layout1->setShowSerName(TRUE);
        //$layout1->setShowBubbleSize(TRUE);
        //$layout1->setShowLeaderLines(TRUE);
        //$layout1->setShowLegendKey(TRUE);
        //$image = base_url().'image/app_req.jpeg';
        //$header1 = new PHPExcel_Worksheet();

        //$header1->setHeaderFooter(PHPExcel_Worksheet_HeaderFooter::addImage($image,'A12'));
        $plotarea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea($layout1, array($series,$total_series));
        $title    = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title($this->lang->line('co_report'), null);  
        //$title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title(new PHPExcel_RichText(new PHPExcel_Cell('A','1','Ttile Chart',PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING,$sheet)));
        $legend   = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, null, false);
        $xTitle   = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title($this->lang->line('course_names'));
        $yTitle   = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title($this->lang->line('no_std'));
        $chart    = new PHPExcel_Chart(
          'chart1',                                       // name
          $title,                                         // title
          $legend,                                        // legend 
          $plotarea,                                      // plotArea
          true,                                           // plotVisibleOnly
          0,                                              // displayBlanksAs
          $xTitle,                                        // xAxisLabel
          $yTitle                                         // yAxisLabel
        );                      
        $chart->setTopLeftPosition('B'.$start_ofChart);
        $chart->setBottomRightPosition('J25');
        //echo "<pre/>";print_r($chart); exit;  
        //echo "<pre/>"; print_r($workbook); exit; 
        $sheet->addChart($chart); 
    }   
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="training report.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 
    $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($workbook, 'Excel2007');
    $writer->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean(); 
    $writer->save('php://output');
```

I should draw two chart in each sheet in a manner that each chart should use from itself data source but the above code cant draw the chart just it write the data source value in the specified column row inside sheet. But if i draw one chart in a sheet the above code is run true.

Comment: and also phpexcel can't support utf-8 or may be other reason when i want to change the worksheet name to the Persian chart generation not woking.

Comment: PHPExcel supports __only__ UTF-8

Comment: But when i set the sheet name if string contain spaces the file can't be open its show message that indicate file is corrupted. So what is the reason?

Comment: Then perhaps there is a fault somewhere, though normally any valid UTF-8 string (including those with spaces) should be accepted... are you absolutely sure that you're using UTF-8? From the above, `//$sheet->setCellValue('H11','ãÌãæÚ ÔÇÑÏÇä');` doesn't look like UTF-8

Comment: Yeah i use utf-8 i found the reason because for naming that contain space we should use 'quotation' with name.                         new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', "'".$sheet_name."'"..'!$B$'.$startRow_num, null, 1),

Comment: That's standard MS Excel behaviour: if you have space in a worksheet name, then references to that worksheet need to be quoted